# Modify the result based on the value in one column in Oracle in Rubyon Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle

I am fetching data from oracle database in Ruby on rails application. Table has amount and type column . If the type is C , i need to add negative sign to the amount and otherwise i need to display the amount as it is in the table
Is there any way to apply this logic while fetching the data itself or after i get the results i need to iterate the results?

My model class

```
 class TransactionFlat < PRecord
   self.table_name = "transaction"
   self.primary_key = "transaction_id"
 end
```

controller code

```
 @transactions = TransactionFlat.where(condition)
```

conditions I framed based on the value from the UI.How can i modify the transactions using the query itself without iterating after the results

Comment: You could use a case statement in the select clause. Something like `.select("transaction.*, (CASE type = C THEN 0 - amount ELSE amount END) as signed_amount")`. But this does also sound like a X&Y problem. Why not use a column type that stores signed numbers?

Comment: Also `type` is somewhat of a reserved word in ActiveRecord. Its used to hold the type (the class) of the record when using polymorphism. This can cause unexpected bugs.

Comment: TransactionType is  the exact name of the column

Comment: I cannot use a new column as the exact value is also needed sometimes. If it is a credit , need to display the amount with negative. In rails how can I change it

Comment: I am getting as undefined if I use the above.can you please share any sample or link